# Overload Ambiguity default interface method

Tags: kotlin

I am calling the java.util.spi.ToolProvider interface, and when I all `run` in Kotlin I get an overload ambiguity error.

There are two run methods of identical signatures, one is a default method, and the other is unimplemented.  They are both in the same class, how do I resolve this error?

```
val jar = ToolProvider.findFirst("jar").orElseThrow()
jar.run(null, null, "--create", "file=foo.jar", "--main-class=foo.bar", "-C", "baz", ".")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two run methods of identical signatures

There aren't, and there couldn't be: this wouldn't compile. Because, well, there wouldn't be any way to resolve the ambiguity.

In this case, the two methods have different types for first two parameters. So you need to specify them, e.g. if you want the `PrintStream`-taking method:

```
jar.run(null as PrintStream?, null as PrintStream?, "--create", "file=foo.jar", "--main-class=foo.bar", "-C", "baz", ".")
```

Note that documentation says

> Throws:    NullPointerException - **if any of the arguments are null**, or if there are any null values in the args array

so for these methods you wouldn't run into the problem with a valid call in the first place.